# TypeError in Javascript

Tags: javascript

```
function url_info()
{
    var url_val=document.getElementsByClassName("spc-tab");
    var current_s=0;
    for(var i=0;i<url_val.length;i++)
    {
        var url_class=url_val[i].className.split(" ");
        if(url_class[1]!=null)
        {
            if(url_class[1]=="selected")
            {
                current_s=i;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    var temp_1=url_val[current_s].text;          //**Error here**
    return(temp_1);
}
```

In this function url_info i am getting the TypeError But i don't know why?? .... as My var current_s is defined within the scope and integer...

Comment: it's not an array, it's a `HTML Collection`

Comment: not sure what an elements `text` property is supposed to be though!

Comment: to get the inner Html inside a variable.

Comment: All of this code can be reduced to `document.querySelector(".spc-tab.selected").textContent;`.

Comment: Why not use `innerHTML` instead?

Comment: @adarsh What do you mean? `text` isn’t a property that exists on any `HTMLElement`. Also, the TypeError isn’t reproducible. I suspect, the `.text` part isn’t what your code really looks like.

Comment: @JaromandaX that's exactly my point. it's a HTML collection in array form so `.` won't work here

Comment: @ThatBird I want to return a Value for other Functions So innerHtml will work here?? I don't think so..

Comment: @Lokesh *"so . won't work here"* - What?? that makes absolutely zero sense ... your point was that it was an array ... it isn't

Comment: @Xufox when I add this code in Mozilla console ... It works but I want to run it through HTML script ...

Comment: @Lokesh What is an “HTML collection in array form”? Why should `.` not work here?

Comment: @adarsh Yes I think you are trying to get the content of the element with the class name `spc-tab` and specifying the condition. you can use `var temp_1=url_val[current_s].innerHTML;` will give you the content

Comment: @JaromandaX It 's an array I just try to console in browser and it's giving me in array form

Comment: @Lokesh [`document.getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) does not return an _Array_, though. It returns an [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection).

Comment: @Xufox After visiting this page it says array like objects https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection

Comment: @Lokesh its  HTMLCOLLECTION ...

Comment: @Lokesh it's not an array - it's "array like"

Comment: @JaromandaX yea got clear. I was confused the way it prints HTMLCollection in console

Comment: @JaromandaX  @Xufox .... Actually My code is Corrected tested through console and it was giving me the desired results... But when I add the same code in HTML file then it is not working ... I tried to print the url_val and got the correct Result in `HtmlCollection` ... But After that error begins .... I tried url_val.length which is giving me 0.. means my `HTMLCOLLECTION` is Empty.

Comment: so, `document.getElementsByClassName("spc-tab")` is returning an empty HTMLCollection ... which is why you get the error ... you're probably calling `url_info` before any elements with that class exist - which is a common error, trying to run javascript before the page loads

Comment: @JaromandaX     ......... Yeah Thanks........I got the error... actually  spc-tab was also generated by Js ......... So, I added the code at the end and added a waiting time of 2.5 sec then it worked thanks

Answer (score 1):

why write this much of code when one line can do:

```
function url_info() {
  var temp_1 = "";
  var url_val = document.querySelector(".spc-tab.selected");

  temp_1 = url_val[0].text > 0 ? url_val[0].text : temp_1; 
  return (temp_1);
}
```

and second, you don't require to convert your class name to string then split. You just can access them through [classlist](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList). Then use contains.

```
function url_info() {
  var url_val = document.getElementsByClassName("spc-tab");
  var current_s = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < url_val.length; i++) {
    var isSelected = url_val[i].classList.contains("selected");
    if (isSelected) {
      current_s = i;
      break;
    }
  }
  var temp_1 = url_val[current_s].text; 
  return (temp_1);
 }
```

Comment: I don't Know why My code is not working in Html file ...... it is working fine when I am adding it in console ..But in Html file it gives error and it is showing me url_val correct ... but after that i tried to check url_val.length  and it is giving me 0 .... but when I printed the url_val on console same script but with console.log(url_val) it is showing me HtmlCollection with 8 entries....